# Constant output for large Matrix Multiplication sizes

Tags: matrix, cuda, floating-point, matrix-multiplication

I am implementing a Matrix Multiplication Code for GPUs, the matrix data type is float and the sizes are very large. So, for large sizes of Matrices I get a constant value **2,147,483,648** which is 2^31.
I get that it is the max range of float, but is there any way by which I can increase the range of  my output to get correct Matrix Multiplication answer without changing the data type?

Comment: Well, I am surprised how the Api's like CUBLAS SGEMM provided by Nvidia can perform Matrix Multplication over a larger range by taking single precision float input and giving single precision floating output.

Comment: Can you rescale the units of your matrices, and sacrifice only precision?

Comment: 2^31 is not the "max range" for float32 types, it (2 − 2^−23) × 2^127. whatever your problem is, it has nothing to do with types.

Comment: Piece of advice: do not implement your own matrix mul, use cublas. For performance this a race you’ll always loose...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, It was a basic mistake I was doing which restricted the value of my output matrices to **2,147,483,648.**

```
for(int i = 0; i < k; i++) 
    {
        sum += A_gpu[row * k + i] * B_gpu[i * m + col];
    }
    C_gpu[row * m + col] = sum;
```

This is a part of my code and the problem was that the variable sum had integer datatype.